# SOAPFaultException on RequestContext of SOAP in IntelliJ evaluation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, soap, fault

During debugging in IntelliJ, I'm getting the `SOAPFaultException` after evaluate the expression (or adding Watching in debug console) in the `RequestContext` object. More specifically, the error says:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SoapClient to nusoap, Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524226/soapclient-to-nusoap-server-did-not-recognize-the-value-of-http-header-soapacti)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to the Map custom implementation of the class RequestContext.java made in the jaxws-rt (version 2.1.4) library. 
The custom map implementation has a Fallback mechanism that when the variable "mapView.fallbackMap" is null the header "soapAction" is clear in the fallback for-loop. Check the snipped bellow:

```
 /**
 * Fill a {@link Packet} with values of this {@link RequestContext}.
 */
public void fill(Packet packet) {
    if(mapView.fallbackMap==null) {
        if (endpointAddress != null)
            packet.endpointAddress = endpointAddress;
        packet.contentNegotiation = contentNegotiation;
        if (soapAction != null) {
            packet.soapAction = soapAction;
        }
        if(!others.isEmpty()) {
            packet.invocationProperties.putAll(others);
            //if it is not standard property it deafults to Scope.HANDLER
            packet.getHandlerScopePropertyNames(false).addAll(others.keySet());
        }
    } else {
        Set<String> handlerScopePropertyNames = new HashSet<String>();
        // fallback mode, simply copy map in a slow way
        for (Entry<String,Object> entry : mapView.fallbackMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            if(packet.supports(key))
                packet.put(key,entry.getValue());
            else
                packet.invocationProperties.put(key,entry.getValue());

            //if it is not standard property it deafults to Scope.HANDLER
            if(!super.supports(key)) {
                handlerScopePropertyNames.add(key);
            }
        }

        if(!handlerScopePropertyNames.isEmpty())
            packet.getHandlerScopePropertyNames(false).addAll(handlerScopePropertyNames);
    }
}
```

Additionaly, the variable "mapView.fallbackMap" is filled every time a method from Map not supported by the custom implementation is made, for example, the "entrySet" or "size" method. Therefore, everytime we call a "Watch" or "Evaluate" operation to debug the RequestContext in IntelliJ IDEA the fallback is filled broken the SOAP call.

So the solution, does not use to debug the RequestContext before SOAP call, or make sure to remove the following property before to execute the request:

```
((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().remove("javax.xml.ws.soap.http.soapaction.uri")
```